# How to batch update multiple image links in InDesign CS5 or CS6?

Tags: adobe-indesign, images, batch-processing

I am using Adobe InDesign CS5.5 and / or CS6 (depending on if this feature can be found in one or the other program). Does anyone know if there is a way to batch update multiple image links in InDesign CS5 or CS6?

In other words, I have edited loads of images that are already linked to an existing document and would now like to update them all without relinking to all of them.

Comment: Are all the updated images located in the same directory? If yes, then update one and the rest will update as well. If the originals are scattered about a system, you'll have to update each image, or at least one image in each separate original directory.

Answer (score 3):

Alt(Option)-Click the "Update Link" button?

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WSDE47C603-CE39-4952-942B-A84893EA06E7a.html

> To update all modified links, choose Update All Links from the Links
>   panel menu, or select a modified link and Alt-click (Windows) or
>   Option-click (Mac OS) the Update Link button.

Comment: ... or close and reopen the InDesign file. Automatically relinks.

Answer (score 3):

I've written quite a few AppleScripts that work for Indesign on the Mac. I can recommend two of them for relinking images.

1. Indesign File Relinker. I wrote this because often I will package a file and send it to someone. They will give it back to me later but the images are still all linked to the packaged folder. I wanted to relink them to my master image folder. This script first asks you if you want to relink i) All, ii) Missing or iii) Selected images. It then asks you to point to the top level directory where you are likely to find these images. It searches through every subdirectory relinking the images and saves an index file at the top level for next time. It can handle instances of images which have different modification dates too. Download it from here: http://www.drscripto.com/?p=8
2. Indesign multiple image relinker. This one is for when you have multiple Indesign documents that share common images. When one of these images gets modified you have to update it in all those Indesign documents. This script updates them all at once. You can use it to relink to a different file too if you want. The script first gives you a list of every COMMON image linked to all the open documents. This one is free: http://www.drscripto.com/?p=118

Let me know what you think, and if you have any other ideas for scripts :-)
David

Answer (score 1):

Short story, InDesign DOES support batching, as follow:

Open the Links window.

Two ways to handle it:

**First way does a little at a time.** If your first sequence of files are from one folder, the next sequence from another (e.g. chapter1, then chapter2 etc files), then select all the first folder's files by clicking the first file and then shift-click the last.

All from that folder get marked. Then click the upper right menu and select Relink to Folder.

Now navigate to the destination folder you want. It will relink all but report the number that didn't get relinked (cuz they aren't in the destination).

Repeat for each chapter.

If any are missing, find them by clicking each file and read the file path in the bottom window. Relink each.

**Second approach didn't prove as convenient for me, because some files were missing in the new destination**.

Similar to above, but select every file in the Links window and relink to the first destination folder. It will report a large number that aren't in that folder. It selects those for you.

Now repeat for each destination folder, till all files have been relinked.

Comment: Your short story might benefit of a few additional paragraph returns 

Answer (score 0):

Another option (although I like the Alt-click by horatio best) is to simply move/delete the files that it is currently referencing and then update one and select the checkboyx to look for other missing files in the same directore. Works only if all files are in the same directory, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

If Adobe InDesign spots multiple missing files in the same directory it automatically batch corrects all the missing links in that folder. Just make sure you don't keep moving files.

This link might help, its a step-by-step relink. 
http://www.earlepress.com/contact-us/support-forum/forumid/8/threadid/14/scope/posts.aspx